# Can I remove multiple items from a DropDownList based on match to partial text

Tags: vb.net, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

I have a drop down list with contents similar to:

> ```
> City1
> City1_SearchCriteria
> City2
> City3
> City3_SearchCriteria
> City4
> City4_SearchCriteria
> ```

I'm wondering if its possible to remove the items in this drop down that contain `_SearchCriteria`

Or should I be looking higher up at the DataSet that is the source of the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally fix the dataset. However, you can easily remove the offending items by working your way backward through the items list and removing the bad ones:

```
    For nI As Integer = cboMyData.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim oItem As ListItem
        oItem = cboMyData.Items(nI)
        If oItem.Text.EndsWith("_SearchCriteria", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            cboDataType.Items.Remove(oItem)
        End If
    Next
```